# Is the Munich Hbf Left Luggage facility available 24 hours?

Tags: luggage-storage, munich, train-stations

Is the Munich Hbf Left Luggage storage facility operational 24 hrs?

I have a night train to Venice on a Sunday night at 11 30PM  and would want to claim my bag at 9PM from the storage section that I intend to deposit in the morning.

Comment: If the train is at 11.30 and you don't need your stuff, claim it at 11.20, but make yourself familiar with the train station so you find the right train. Especially if you have never used German trains before. Munich Hbf is very simple, all the tracks are next to each other. But always read the big board to see if the train is late or the platform got changed. Have fun in Munich. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I [asked Deutsche Bahn on Twitter](https://twitter.com/simbabque/status/659455209001889792).

> Ja, die Schließfächer im Münchener Hbf sind rund um die Uhr zugänglich

That says the lockers in Munich HBF are accessible 24 hours a day.

Comment: @SantoshSridhar If this answer solves your problem mark it as accepted. That's the best way to say thank you.

Comment: I have since been there myself. They are indeed open 24 hours per day.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Deutsche Bahn AG railway information](http://www.bahnhof.de/bahnhof-de/Muenchen_Hbf.html?hl=M%C3%BCnchen), the railway station is open 00:00–24:00 daily, and the station has *Schließfächer*, i.e. luggage lockers.

[image: Luggage lockers]

Luggage lockers at *München Ostbahnhof* ([Source: Münchenwiki](http://www.muenchenwiki.de/wiki/Datei:Ostbahnhof-UG_Schlie%C3%9Ff%C3%A4cher.JPG), GFDL).  Lockers at Hauptbahnhof will look similar.

So, with an unmanned luggage locker, you can put away or retrieve your luggage at any time.

Comment: Looks like we don't have conclusive info..il need to plan carrying my luggage out of the train station;(

Answer (score 6):

[There are two types of luggage storage facilities in Munich Haptbanhof](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/service/luggage-storage/index.html): short-term lockers, and long(ish)-term storage. The lockers are unmanned, and hence I assume that they are accessible 24-hours, or at least during the opening hours of the train station. On the other hand the long-term luggage storage service is manned from 08:00 - 20:00 (Monday - Friday) and 08:00 - 18:00 (Saturday, Sunday and Public Holidays), [according to the SNCF webpage on Munich Hauptbanhof](http://uk.voyages-sncf.com/en/destination/germany/munich/train-station):

> #### LUGGAGE
>
> The station has a Left Luggage office which you can find via the ticket hall. Opening hours: 08:00 - 20:00 (Monday - Friday) and 08:00 - 18:00 (Saturday, Sunday and Public Holidays). Luggage lockers are also available. Lost property facilities are offered at the station and can be located via the ticket hall.

[To locate the two luggage storage facilities see the station map.](https://www.etracker.de/lnkcnt.php?et=gEg009&url=http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fileadmin/media/download/muenchen_hbf.pdf)

Comment: The lockers are definitely accessible 24 hours, but on the station map you're linking to, I can only find the lockers. Where are the other luggage services you're mentioning located?

Comment: SNCF seems an odd source for information on Munich.

Comment: @gerrit Couldn't find the bahn.de page with a search query in english. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO The official information page from the German Railways only lists the lockers and no further luggage service at München Hbf (as linked from gerrit's answer). I am not able to locate any further facilities on the map you are linking to (my question to you where they are located is still open) and though being regularly at München Hbf, I can't remember having seen any further luggage facilities but the lockers. I am honestly in doubt if the information on the SNCF page is either incorrect or outdated.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo [Munich public transport](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/service/luggage-storage/index.html) also mentions a facility to store luggage for up to 4 weeks, as an alternative to the short-term lockers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If you click through the DB link I posted and look at the map of the station, it does list both services.  But the list of services doesn't.